# Does a discrete GPU help for non 3D tasks

Tags: laptop, windows-10, graphics-card, gpu

I'm looking for a new laptop and considering if I should get one with a discrete GPU, like the Dell XPS 15 or the Surface Book. I don't do much 3D stuff, but would love the fastest laptop possible for normal Windows tasks.
So, does a discrete GPU speed up general Windows tasks like browsing, etc?
 I know that for example Chrome has hardware acceleration. So one would assume it does help? Or is this negligible for movies and browsing?

Comment: Hardware video decoders in most onboard GPUs mean videos are decoded easily anyway, even a HD3000 or 4000 is plenty. You've no use case for a discrete card.

Comment: So really, the only use of a discrete GPU is for gaming?

Comment: No. For gaming. OpenCL, CUDA, ... but not (yet) for most common tasks, though we number of openCL apps seems to be increasing.

Comment: @Remy As above, Gaming, CAD, Video Encoding & Editing, Image processing, scientific research, cryptocurrencies. Just not much else for average Joe yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So one would assume it does help?

Most of the time: No, you will not notice much speedup.

But... If you have a CPU with the GPU on the same die then disabling that GPU will mean less heat produced on that die. That means more thermal headroom for the CPU. So I expect a minor speed gain when the CPU is heavily used.

If it is mostly idle it should have plenty headroom for an accosional turbo, in which case the boost should be minimal. Hence the "when the CPU is heavily used". And at that point you might be better off considering a desktop.

> Or is this negligible for movies and browsing?

I expect it to be measureable with benchmarks, but mostly negligible.